# jPLayer Playlist get song name on change

Tags: jquery, jplayer, playlist

I'm using jplayer playlist with **autoplay**. Playlist is shown, songs are playing,it is ok. But I want to get current songs name when jplayer changes to next song. I couldnt find any documentation for this.

How can I get the current song name when song is changed?

Here is jplayer playlist sample code.

```
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
  jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
  cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
}, [
  {
    title:"Song 1",
    artist:"Artist 1",
    mp3:"http://www.example.com/audio/song1.mp3",
    oga:"http://www.example.com/audio/song1.ogg"
  },
  {
    title:"Song 2",
    artist:"Artist 2",
    mp3:"http://www.example.com/audio/song2.mp3",
    oga:"http://www.example.com/audio/song2.ogg"
  }
], {
  playlistOptions: {
    autoPlay: true,
    enableRemoveControls: true
  },
  swfPath: "/js",
  supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
  smoothPlayBar: true,
  keyEnabled: true,
  audioFullScreen: false // Allows the audio poster to go full screen via keyboard
});
```

Comment: If the song is changing, what do you mean by 'the current song name'? The one that has ended or the one that has started playing?

Comment: yes.with autoplay, next song is started automatically when previous is ended. I want to get song name when it changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the [playlist addon](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) of jPlayer, from the docs:

> The third parameter is an object to define the jPlayer options and
>   jPlayerPlaylist options. This object is passed to jPlayer (...)

And [here](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events) you can see the list of available events of jPlayer. The one useful for your question is:

> $.jPlayer.event.play * Occurs when the media is played.

So, in your code, you could add a last parameter to override the `play` event of jPlayer. There you can access the title of the song being played at that moment:

```
play: function(e) {
    console.log(e.jPlayer.status.media.title);
}
```

Comment: Ohh, how did I miss the third paramater can be used for jplayer.events. I'll try. Thanks zed.

Comment: @bencagri, you're welcome, remember to mark as answer if it answered your question.